# Initial Zoom position in JQuery plugin Smooth Zoom Pan

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the JQuery plugin Smooth Zoom Pan.

http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142

I am using initial_POSITION parameter for giving initial zoom position to my image but I always get an empty space above the image.

Smooth Zoom is initialised like:

```
$('#ImageID').smoothZoom({
      width: '100%',
      height: 600,
      button_SIZE: 22,
      button_ALIGN: "bottom center",
      zoom_OUT_TO_FIT: false,
      button_AUTO_HIDE: "YES",
      button_AUTO_HIDE_DELAY: 1,
      initial_ZOOM: '35',
      initial_POSITION: '10 50'
});
```

Comment: Since your question is related to 3rd party plugin, you have to go through the documentation or request support from plugin developer.

Comment: I tried but they not proving support currently for this plugin and also didn't find any help in documentation.

Comment: I think it's bug with the plugin, if you check this demo http://vectorflower.com/preview/smooth_zoom/sample4.html and click on Focus to (Location 3), it is creating blank space at right side.

Comment: I solved this issue by editing plugin JS file. thanks